# an upper bound on Wave Front

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, distribution-theory

Can you please help  to understand how to solve this question:

Let $f^{ij}(x)$ be a positive definite matrix smoothly varying with $x$ and define

$\square=D_{t}^{2}-\sum_{i,j}f^{ij}(x)D_{x_{i}}D_{x_{j}}$

suppose $\square$u is smooth, find an upper bound on WF(u).

Thank you!